# Couette-Poiseuille flow between non-parallel plates

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I have a Couette-Poiseuille flow (both flows combined) where the plates are not parallel. So h, the thickness of the flow, changes along the x axis.

Can I use a mean h to calculate the viscid stress? Is this procedure correct?

$τ_v=-μ_a  v/h+|∆p_L |h/2L$ (I know the Poiseuille equation for parallel plates includes the y coordinate, but I substituted for h, the height I'm interested in to calculate the stress.

$τ_v=-1/(h_1-h_2 ) ∫〖μ_a  v/h〗 dh+1/(h_1-h_2 ) ∫|∆p_L |h/2Ldh$

The integration limits are $h_1$ and $h_2$ and the former is greater than the latter. Both are the thickness limits and I'm still too new to this forum, so I can't put them where they should be.

This is the result I got:

$τ_v=-μ_a  v/(h_1-h_2 )  ln⁡(h_1/h_2 )+|∆p_L |(h_1+h_2)/4L$

Right or wrong?

Comment: Do you have any image or diagram of the set-up? I am wondering because I thought that Couette and Poiseuille flows were determined by steady flows between infinite plates (don't quote me on that!), and I don't see how that can be the case if non-parallel.

Comment: No, I don't.  They are finite plates and non-parallel. The shortest thickness is 0.5 mm and the longest is 1.3 mm.